# OCR With Python and tesseract number not working on specific sample image

Tags: python, numbers, ocr, tesseract

i'm trying to use tesseract to write the numbers in this frame, but my code is not working.

Any help?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Xep.png)

```html
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as Img
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

demo=Image.open("/Users/Desktop/image_frames/frame37.png")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(demo)
print(text)
```

Comment: is there an error? a wrong output? please give some more information

Comment: It give me no text recognition. When i try with a normal white background and black text it works good.

Comment: Your sample image looks like you might be able to search for text in specific areas. Did you try to convert the image to black and white or grayscale?

Answer (score 0):

i got decent results when playing a bit with the page segmentation modes, e.g. PSM 11 and also cutting your image to cut off the coloured area

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img_cv = cv2.imread("/Users/Desktop/image_frames/frame37.png")

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
height, width = img_rgb.shape[:2]
img_cut = img_rgb[0:height, int(width/1.2):width]

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_cut,lang='eng', config='--psm 11 --oem 1')

print(text)
```

Giving you:

```
100
26
20
-30
♀
```

Comment: This is really helpful! , any textbook or site for further studies or raccomandation?